# Blur (filter under an element with a higher z-index

Tags: jquery, css, filter, blur

Structure

```
<header>
-top element
-has 0.8 opacity
-fixed to top of window

<section>
-contains content that will scroll under header
-content that gets pushed under the header will show through
```

I want to apply a blur to content that gets pushed under the header. (About 100px tall) I don't want to apply a blur to the whole section, just the part that is under the header element. Is there a way to achieve partial blurring?

Comment: How will you be figuring out blurring ?

Comment: That's what I need help figuring out. I only know of the CSS blur, but that blurs the whole element and it doesn't seem like I can limited to only a certain area.

Comment: You can create a blurred div beneath header with same height as of header with transparency. Maybe it will show the content also blurred. I haven't tried it but will work on it later some time.

Comment: I've tried that, but the blur filter will blur only the element it is applied to. Unfortunately, the blur doesn't work on the elements below.

Comment: Hey I found this: http://www.blurjs.com/.